# What are the defining characteristics of dubstep as an electronic music genre?

Tags: genre, electronic-music, genre-characteristics, dubstep

I know many dubstep styles don't use the "[wobble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubstep#Wobble_bass)" effect at all, and that the "wobble" effect is used by many other genres, so it's not a defining characteristic, even if it's sometimes considered a genre's cliche.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubstep) includes some characteristics:

> tightly coiled productions with overwhelming bass lines and reverberant drum patterns, clipped samples, and occasional vocals

But that applies to a huge chunk of the electronic music universe. The rhythm section further specifies:

> Dubstep rhythms are usually syncopated, and often shuffled or incorporating tuplets. The tempo is nearly always in the range of 138–142 beats per minute, with a clap or snare usually inserted every third beat in a bar

But that also applies to a huge portion of electronic music. It applies to them all if you consider the pitch control of a dj context. It's not rare to see house, techno, and trance productions with those characteristics, that would be hardly considered dubstep.

If that's not it, then what is defining dubstep as a musical genre? Which are the patterns that define a dubstep song? Is it possible to define dubstep in more precise, less generalized, terms? What makes a dubstep song a dubstep song, that isn't shared by pretty much every other electronic music genre?

Answer (score 3):

> > with a clap or snare usually inserted every third beat in a bar [...]
>
> But that also applies to a huge portion of electronic music

This doesn't apply to a huge portion of electronic music. Most styles have the clap/snare every other beat, not every third. And that's, to me, one of the defining characteristics of dubstep, that is **the half-time rhythm** that, mixed with the other characteristics you mentioned (wobble (sometimes), bass-heavy productions...) make dubstep dubstep.

Comment: But how is the snare on the third beat related to double-time rhythm?

Comment: @AntondB yeah, I misread that quote the other way around. It's more confusing than anything. What I meant was *half*-time rhythm.

Comment: But how is the snare on the third beat related to half-time rhythm? Or any specific rhythm? Is it supposed to be syncopation? Is it supposed to be a strong beat? What do we mean by half-time rhythms? Rhythms in 2/2? Is 2/2 rhythm really that prevalent, or expected, in dubstep?

Comment: Usually electronic music (snare/clap on every other beat) goes "boom-cha-boom-cha", dubstep (snare/clap every third beat in a bar) goes (boom-pause-cha-pause) making it seem like it's going half the speed (e.g. 140 bpms sound like 70 bpms). That's what I mean by half time. See the first picture in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-time_(music)#Half-time) of the wikipedia article on half time.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean now!